# Why is html.fromstring in my code not working?

Tags: python, html

I am using `html.fromstring` in the folloing code:

```
import html
import sys
url = "https://tokcount.com/?user=totallynotbenandoliver"
response = requests.get(url)
try:
  response = requests.get(url)
except:
  print ('Sorry bad url') 
  sys.exit(2)
if response.status_code != 200:
  print ('Sorry invalid response ' + str(response.status_code))
  sys.exit(2)
tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
extracteditems = tree.xpath("//span[@class=”odometer-value”]/text()")
print("\n".join(extracteditems))
```

And my debugger is returning:

```
  File "c:\Users\ojspr\OneDrive\Desktop\Unity stuffs\TickTok Reader\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
AttributeError: module 'html' has no attribute 'fromstring'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless `html.fromstring` is undocumented, there is no mention of this method in the [`html` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html). Please cite the source upon which you're basing your implicit claim to the contrary, as it's not clear how you arrived at this conclusion.

Comment: That error means that there's no any method `fromstring` in python's `html` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [lxml](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) library

```
from lxml import html
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use the wrong module.

I [searched](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/) and found `lxml` for the code you wrote...

```
!pip install lxml
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
```